# Logitech mouse - scrolling

Tags: scrolling, logitech-mouse, scroll-wheel

I have Logitech Anywhere mouse MX. When I try to scroll up, I can do it, but after that, webpage (or document) automaticly scrolles down for one line. The same thing happens when I try to scroll down. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you installed SetPoint?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find settings for that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**this**](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Anywhere-Mouse-MX-scroll-wheel-not-working-properly-or-not/td-p/448691) advice:

> Setpoint clearly is the problem. All was well on my windows re-install
>   until I installed it.
>
> 1) **Avoid Setpoint**
>
> 2) If you already installed it, **disable smooth scrolling** and also let
>   the OS handle the mouse settings (not Setpoint).

Comment: Could you tell me please, how can I let the OS handle the mouse settings (not Setpoint)? I have win7 Pro 32 bit

Comment: Change the setting to "OS implementation"  rather than the default "SetPoint implementation"

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system?

I am using windows 10 and with or without set point my anywhere mouse works different ways when I have the scroll set to 'precision' or 'super-speed'.

When my click wheel is engaged for precision I sometimes have trouble dragging windows and highlighting text etc.

My solution was to keep my mouse disengaged from the precision scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, SetPoint is really problematic, and the latest version available at the moment, the 6.67.83, is dated from Sep 08, 2015, which is ridiculously old.

On my Windows 10 v1709 x64 (Updated Nov. 2017), installing SetPoint 6.67.83 x64 is really a pain because, when this software is installed, even when disabling “Smooth Scrolling” and checking the “OS Implementation” option in the parameters is not satisfying for me.

The only option here, at least for me, to have the basic SetPoint features (like the OSD, the Unifying tool, ...) is to stick with the 6.32 version.

SetPoint 6.32 is really the most reliable version out there, even on modern OSs, like Windows 10 x64. It isn't really difficult to find, but for your information its SHA-1 for the x64 version is `38956805b9f91852b7f87bddce2341e5d4f65d21`.

Comment: SetPoint is not mentioned in the question. Please edit your post so that it reads as an answer to the original question.